# VBA If with color

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, colors

I have this code in VBA:

```
Function SBarvou(range)
If range.Value = "R" Then
    SBarvou = "O"
If range.Value = "R" And range.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then
    SBarvou = "O"
    SBarvou.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
End If
End If
```

End Function

The first part is working, but when the source cell is yellow (RGB 255,255,0) then it does not work. I need it to when source cell contain R and is yellow, then to be product cell O and yellow too.

How to repair it please?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Do you get error message? Wrong result? How it's formatted to yellow (manual or conditional formatting)? Did you tried debugging your code?

Comment: Im getting #VALUE! error. Its formatted manually.

Comment: A function called by the worksheet cannot change the format of a cell.

Comment: So how (is) it possible to solve this please?

Comment: you also missing data types `SBarvou = "O"` makes `SBarvou` a string but in `SBarvou.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)` you treat it as a range object. Please explain your goal a bit more detailed to help you find a solution.

Comment: Its not with a function called from the sheet as a formula.  One would need to write a sub that is run manually or in a Worksheet event.

Comment: What is the end result you're looking for? Your function as written is only going to return the character "O" - what exactly are you looking for it to do?

Comment: Ok, I was just wondering, if it is possible with just one function. I know that I can create a sub. So thanks for help.
@Werrf I needed to color product cell If source cell is colored too.